# Encode strings to SCALE encoded smart contract calls

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, smart-contract

I'm looking for a way to encode smart contract calls in javascript code with polkadot-js, the same way I can do it from the web UI, but I cannot find a description of the available API in the [documentation](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start)

1. is there a better documentation somewhere describing the methods and their arguments available somewhere?
2. How should I use the ABI in my .contract file to encode a function call to a smart contract?

The contract is written in ink and the chain uses the contracts pallet.

*Parts of the functionally will use some code written in Rust and executed as wasm in the browser so if it is easier to do in no_std rust that is also an option for me*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not documented anywhere unfortunately. You don't use the .contract file directly, but create an `Abi` instance from it.

Taking flipper as an example, the steps would be like so:

1. Create an `Abi` object either directly or by creating a `ContractPromise`

```
const abi = new Abi(flipper.json, api.registry.getChainProperties())
```

```
const contract = new ContractPromise(api, flipper.json, address)
const abi = contract.abi
```

2. Encode your call input

```
const inputData = abi.messages["flip"].toU8a([true])
```

You can use this encoded data for runtime calls where the arguments are not encoded automatically.

If you use api-contract and do contract calls via the ContractPromise interface the data is encoded for you. Just need to pass an array with values for the message params.

```
contract.tx["flip"]({gasLimit, storageDepositLimit}, true).signAndSend(...)
```